# For nth-child loop, change style of article elements that are nested at different levels

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For each article, how do I loop through a set of 6 background colors if elements are nested at different levels?

Is this possible with CSS or will I have to add a class name to each of the articles (.loop1-6)? I'd prefer not to go the JS route.

```css
article:nth-child(6n+1) {
  background: red;
}

article:nth-child(6n+2) {
  background: blue;
}

article:nth-child(6n+3) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div>
    <article>1 - red</article>
  </div>
  <div>
    <article>2 - blue</article>
  </div>
  <div>
    <article>3 - orange</article>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <article>4 - green</article>
    </div>
    <div>
      <article>5 - purple</article>
    </div>
    <div>
      <article>6 - pink</article>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ...loop repeats... -->
  <div>
    <article>1 - red</article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that the order you put in your code above is the order it will stay in.

```css
.home > div:nth-child(4n + 1) {
    color:red;
}

.home > div:nth-child(4n + 2) {
    color:blue;
}

.home > div:nth-child(4n + 3) {
    color:orange;
}

.home > div:nth-child(4n + 4) {
    color:green;
}

.home > div > div:nth-child(2) {
    color:purple;
}

.home > div > div:nth-child(3) {
    color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
    <div>
        <article>1 - red</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <article>2 - blue</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <article>3 - orange</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <article>4 - green</article>
        </div>
        <div>
            <article>5 - purple</article>
        </div>
        <div>
            <article>6 - pink</article>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ...loop repeats... -->
    <div>
        <article>1 - red</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <article>2 - blue</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <article>3 - orange</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <article>4 - green</article>
        </div>
        <div>
            <article>5 - purple</article>
        </div>
        <div>
            <article>6 - pink</article>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <article>1 - red</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <article>2 - blue</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <article>3 - orange</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <article>4 - green</article>
        </div>
        <div>
            <article>5 - purple</article>
        </div>
        <div>
            <article>6 - pink</article>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <article>1 - red</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <article>2 - blue</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <article>3 - orange</article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <article>4 - green</article>
        </div>
        <div>
            <article>5 - purple</article>
        </div>
        <div>
            <article>6 - pink</article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nudLz4jq/)**

Comment: This is much simpler than the monster I put together. Except I think I would have used simple numbers for the nested divs, as opposed to a calculation. Nice work.

Comment: @Michael_B You might have missed my update I did a few mins ago that changed just that. Not sure why I included them in the first place...

Comment: Oh, now I see that. Even better.